# Excel VBA Chart Maximum Scale Error

Tags: vba, excel, charts, axis

Two issues with this code that I need some help on, I'm new to vba and not sure what the cause of the issues are.

First issue is that when `Me.Range("L7") = Format(Me.Range("C4")....)` gets formatted it puts the date in american format "mm/dd/yyyy". However, the next line Me.Range("L8") is put into the correct "dd/mm/yyyy" format?

Second issue is, when I am changing the chart maximum axis I get a type mismatch error, yet the minimum axis scale changes works perfectly fine?

Any help appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
answer = MsgBox("This will prepare the workbook for the next month, are you sure?", vbYesNo)
If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Range("c34") = "=DATE($B$2,$A$2,A34)" 'enters formula into cell c34
Range("a2") = Month(Date) - 1 'changes month to last month
Range("a3") = Year(Date)
If Month(Date) - 1 <> Month(Range("c34")) Then
    Range("C34").Clear 'checks if last date in column is in same month, if not, clear
End If

myLR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'grabs date in last row
Me.Range("L7") = Format(Me.Range("c4"), "dd/mm/yyyy") 'gets start date of month and formats it
Me.Range("L8") = Format(Me.Cells(myLR, 3).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'gets last date of month and formats it
Range("K7") = "First Day of Month"
Range("K8") = "Last Day of Month"

'Chart section
    Sheets("Site 5").Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Sheets("data input").Range("L7")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Sheets("data input").Range("L8")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not suitable to change cell's value by format function.
It is better to change cell's format by NumberFormatLocal.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
answer = MsgBox("This will prepare the workbook for the next month, are you sure?", vbYesNo)
If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Range("c34") = "=DATE($B$2,$A$2,A34)" 'enters formula into cell c34
Range("a2") = Month(Date) - 1 'changes month to last month
Range("a3") = Year(Date)

If Month(Date) - 1 <> Month(Range("c34")) Then
    Range("C34").Clear 'checks if last date in column is in same month, if not, clear
End If

myLR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'grabs date in last row
'Me.Range("L7") = Format(Me.Range("c4"), "dd/mm/yyyy") 'gets start date of month and formats it
Me.Range("L7") = Me.Range("c4")
Me.Range("L7").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"
'Me.Range("L8") = Format(Me.Cells(myLR, 3).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'gets last date of month and formats it
Me.Range("L8") = Me.Cells(myLR, 3).Value
Me.Range("L8").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Range("K7") = "First Day of Month"
Range("K8") = "Last Day of Month"

'Chart section
    Sheets("Site 5").Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Sheets("data input").Range("L7")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Sheets("data input").Range("L8")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```